# New to Python, what am I doing wrong and not seeing <A> tag (links) returned with BS4

Tags: python, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and learning it. Basically I am trying to pull all the links from my e-commerce store products that is stored in the html below. I'm getting no results returned though and I can't seem to figure out why not.

```
<h3 class="two-lines-name">
    <a title="APPLE IPOD IPOD A1199 2GB" target="_self" href="/Item/Details/APPLE-IPOD-IPOD-A1199-2GB/d1003297dbe7443c8953750f0c96c62a/400">
        APPLE IPOD IPOD A1199 2GB
    </a>
</h3>
```

**This is my python code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def my_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'www.buya.com/Store/SAM-S-LOCKER/400?page=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'h3 class': "two-lines-name"}):
            href = link.get('href')
            print(href)
        page += 1

    my_spider(5)
```

**Result with no data**

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Add debugging print statements so you can see where you are actually getting to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually running the function if you have the function call inside the actual function, after you correct that you are going to get an error as that is not a valid url to pass to requests, last your `soup.findAll('a', {'h3 class': "two-lines-name"})` is not going to find anything:

```
def my_spider(max_pages):
    # use range from 1 to max pages 
    for i in range(1, max_pages+1):
        url = 'http://www.buya.com/Store/SAM-S-LOCKER/400?page={}'.format(i) # http:/?...
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        # you want the h3 tags and to extract the href from the a tags
        for link in soup.findAll("h3", {'class': "two-lines-name"}):
            href = link.a["href"]
            print(href)


my_spider(5) # outside the function
```

Output:

```
/Item/Details/12-FT-CHAIN-W-HOOK/cbb1eb65b100459283d15102606208c2/400
/Item/Details/12-INCH-FUSION-SUBWOOFER/534c4d677b2547fb814668b7d061df5d/400
/Item/Details/18-Gold-Chain-14K-Yellow-Gold-2-03g/0aaf2e1e5532461884cb44e786329e80/400
/Item/Details/1820-HANDMADE-STRAIGHT-RAZOR/ed0ba44f98224067b595b726bf01f5ab/400
/Item/Details/2-PAIRS-OF-POCKET-PLIERS-LEATHERMAN/410bcb9e4321426487bee7639b3cb96e/400
/Item/Details/20TH-CENTURY-FOX-Motorcycle-Helmet-RACING-HELMET/e12a75dc7e004e5aa43698c1edf87773/400
/Item/Details/30-CLUBS/a65f1cbff00c4d59ac998dee96eed98b/400
/Item/Details/30-STEEL-CHAINSAW-BLADE/daaca24ede1341c58bb0d0cd32051646/400
/Item/Details/5-GALLON-GLASS-JUG-BREWING-JUG-CHANGE-JAR/dde9b1bfea2a4a23ad93da098ffc674d/400
/Item/Details/5150-SNOWBOARDS-Snowboard-5150-155CM/bcaa07c71c8c4b499a70d34459244f75/400
/Item/Details/6-FT-STEEL-CHAIN/7c24fb1a16ac46e7b9e91f99883652f6/400
/Item/Details/6-5-CUSTOM-HUNTING-KNIFE/ffda1685b2324abe96e3fb7cb6f7f265/400
/Item/Details/95150/39cb080edd474eb6b770b26b40e3dc6b/400
/Item/Details/ACER-Monitor-P201W/ff03d9c33ca747e08e4646d2c3d5143e/400
/Item/Details/ACOUSTIC-RESEARCH-Monitor-Speakers-RESEARCH-AW825/856ff1d8beb9480d893f94d9d49a8642/400
/Item/Details/ACTIVISION-Microsoft-XBOX-360-CALL-OF-DUTY-BLACK-OPS-2-XBOX-360/aef62055b4f14e379f2eea154d162551/400
/Item/Details/ACTIVISION-Video-Game-Accessory-DJ-HERO-95837809/41e3c7f0114e497caf23d8a50fe1f547/400
/Item/Details/ACTIVISION-Video-Game-Accessory-WII-FIT/7daee2a759a54dd7a4e2b6acd37b9c3e/400
/Item/Details/AIMTECH-1911-SCOPE-MOUNT/ac69ae1c40fe4d7db8c53a8ebf842d7d/400
/Item/Details/AIRCO-TIG-WELDING-TUNGSTEN-Arc-Welder-ELECTRODE/70b9b35db0c547c29eb90e02ef60d91a/400
/Item/Details/AIWA-Portable-CD-Player-XP-SP911/75761bfff9a44093be51e4d70410bd85/400
/Item/Details/ALESSI-Gent-s-Wristwatch-KARIM-RASHID/251c3f95173f49078722b301e1d920fe/400
/Item/Details/ALL-AMERICAN-RIDER-Motorcycle-Part-SADDLE-BAGS/87634c0c08d2458ba5b84fa39c9bc3fc/400
/Item/Details/ALL-AMERICAN-RIDER-Motorcycle-Part-SADDLE-BAGS/803f6dfdc9f44326a5a52b63681779ad/400
/Item/Details/ALLY-SKATEBAORD-USED/716cec1588d9408e859718f5961e1ec6/400
/Item/Details/ALPINE-ARCHERY-Bow-FRONTIER/e73dda8034cf4cdb8ebeeebc9683b55d/400
/Item/Details/AMAZON-Tablet-KINDLE-D01100/ea9ac5b291ef487ea6f75ca328e05750/400
/Item/Details/AMAZON-Tablet-KINDLE-FIRE-D01400/ebe0e7001ac744ffa030fd153942a548/400
/Item/Details/APPLE-Computer-Accessories-A1023/6a38f60d2e034dc597043cc42282246e/400
/Item/Details/APPLE-Cell-Phone-Smart-Phone-IPHONE-5C-A1532-AT-T/cc65c513e848475c8000b6e10b6855e5/400
/Item/Details/APPLE-IPOD-IPOD-A1199-2GB/d1003297dbe7443c8953750f0c96c62a/400
...................................................
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. Fixed the Tabular and am seeing the error.

Comment: Just compared the changes and this makes sense. Thank you Padraic, I'm very new to this so following tutorials, practicing and learning with things I can utilize for a purpose.

Comment: @user277910, no prob.glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your tabulation is wrong... you're calling my_spider inside the my_spider function...
Remove the tabulation on the last line and it should work fine.